# Open screen process in terminal from script

Tags: ssh, java, gnu-screen

I have a minecraft server running in screen, and right now, it is just a script that starts java like so:

`screen -dmS mc java -Xincgc -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.6.4-b2882.jar`

Basically this just starts minecraft in a screen container in the background, and I can access it with `screen -r mc` through SSH. However, what I would like to do, is have the process always up on the server monitor, and also accessible through ssh with `screen -x mc`. Also, I have a restart.sh script that stuffs the stop command to the mc process every two hours, then it executes the start.sh script. The server is at runlevel 3, so I don't think `gnome-terminal -e "screen -x mc"` will work. Also, it seems like the restart script is starting mc outside of screen. When I SSH into the server, `screen -ls` turns up nothing, but the minecraft server process is running and I can connect to it. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

screen -x mc
screen -s mc stuff "say Server Restarting in 15 minutes."
screen -s mc -X eval "stuff \015"
sleep 600
screen -x mc
screen -x mc -X stuff "say Server restarting in 5 minutes."
screen -s mc -X eval "stuff \015"
sleep 240
screen -x mc
screen -s mc -X stuff "say Server restarting in 1 minute."
screen -s mc -X eval "stuff \015"
sleep 60
screen -S mc -X stuff "say Server restarting."
screen -S mc -X eval "stuff \015"
screen -S -X stuff "kickall Server Restarting, it should be back up in about a minute."
screen -S mc -X eval "stuff \015"
sleep 2
screen -S mc -X stuff "stop"
screen -S mc -X eval "stuff \015"
sleep 30
screen -wipe
sleep 3
cd /minecraft/server/craftbukkit
./start.sh
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You said `screen -ls` doesn't show any processes. Are you checking as the right user? Check the `pstree` command to show the parent process of the java command; if it is running inside screen, use `lsof -p <screenpid>` to see what the name of the screen session is (it's one of the open unix socket names).

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, I think that was the issue, I was running restart.sh as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach, in my opinion, would be to use an init script to manage your application.

Some examples :

- http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script/
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html

Ensure that your process logs its output to a file and using "tail -f" command you will be able to "have the process always up on the server monitor, and also accessible through ssh"

Comment: I like the idea of using an init script to manage the process, but I don't think tail will work, since I also want to be able to execute commands from the server itself.